# Why do so few people vote for the Green Party?

Tags: united-states, parties, presidential-election

Now, I don't have comprehensive knowledge of what the Green Party represents, and I only just recently learned of their existence. But from the wikipedia page, it seems like they stand for everything that is objectively morally right:

> The party...promotes environmentalism, nonviolence, social justice,
>   participatory grassroots democracy, gender equality, LGBT rights,
>   anti-war and anti-racism. On the political spectrum the party is
>   generally seen as left-wing, and in 2016 officially self-described as
>   an "eco-socialist" party.

Despite this, they seem to have very little support, with only about 2% of the popular vote going to them. Why is this?

Comment: "objectively morally right" is kind of contradictory, and too much opinion-based. Now, maybe you could reword the question to ask why the difference of votes with the Democratic Party, which is generally supporting the same value.

Comment: Duplicate: why 3rd party support is so low was answered before.

Comment: Also, when people hear "socialism" they remember that [Venezuelans have no food, no money and no freedom](https://www.google.com/search?q=venezuela+collapse). Perhaps they object to such outcome?

Comment: @SJuan76 "Objectively morally right" is not contradictory. The statement "morally right" is not subjective. There are subjective moral beliefs, but there are also objective moral facts.